# upcoming 3 day from today b/w two dates rails currently it calculate only for today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
def self.leave_day 
 self.where("? BETWEEN start_date AND end_date", Date.today).where(status: "Approved").count
end
```

but i want to calculate from today to next 3 days .Now it is calculate b/w two dates where status is today if give range of dates (Date.today +1)..(Date.today + 3.days) it is not accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with a range is not accepted? U could do it with a range and set the `start_date` to the beginning of the date and the `end_date` to the end of the day.

```rb
def self.leave_day 
 self.where(start_date: (Date.today.beginning_of_day)..((Date.today + 3.days).end_of_day), status: 'Approved').count
end
```

Comment: the above function calculate leaves from today to next 3 days but i want to calculate it b/w start_date and end_date and it start calculate from tomarrow e.g  date = 10, 11, 12 it should not calculate today.date

Comment: In that case you could do `((Date.today + 1.day).beginning_of_day)..((Date.today + 2.days).end_of_day)`

Comment: But  it does not cover the end_date senrio for e.g if approved date is b/w 7 and 13 it is not select any thing

Comment: To make sure: You want to have all records where start_date AND end_date are in the range of the upcoming 3 days and the status should be approved?

Comment: Yes I want the upcoming three days b/w startdate and enddate which is stored in db

Comment: Now you confuse me. Let's say startdate is: 01-01-2020 and enddate is: 05-01-2020. Now you want the upcoming three days that are between 01-01-2020 and 05-01-2020? That doesn't makes sense anymore to me. If today would be 03-01-2020 than the upcoming 3 days would return 04-01-2020 and 05-01-2020?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use multiple params on `where`.

I think it should be like this :

```
def self.leave_day 
  self.where("start_date >= ? AND end_date <= ?", Date.today, Date.today + 3.days).where(status: "Approved").count
end
```

Source : https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

Comment: thanks for answer but it cannot count if  start_date = 8  and end_date = 13 for e.g